# CSS different properties on different screen size

Tags: html, css

When the screen size becomes a certain size (560px), I would like the html code to be edited slightly.

At any size > 560px:

```
<div id = "div"><span class = "span">TextRightHere</span></div>
```

At any size < 560px:

```
<div id = "div"><span class = "span">Text<br>Right<br>Here</span></div>
```

How am I able to edit this line of HTML through my CSS file?

Comment: No you are not able to do it with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to the following:

```
<div id = "div"><span class = "span">Text<br>Right<br>Here</span></div>
```

Then, use the following css code:

```
#div br{display:none;}
@media screen and (min-width:560px){
    #div br{display:none;}
}@media screen and (max-width:560px){
    #div br{display:inline;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, but `<br />` can receive `display:none;` and `display:block;` just like any other element.

Armed with this knowledge, use `display:none` by default, then use a media query to apply `display:block` when the width is too narrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the HTML with CSS but you could add [`word-wrap: break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) to make your text fit on smaller screens.

Comment: hi, this only half solves my problem... how do I make it so only the Text, Right, and Here parts get split up and not each individual letter?

Comment: You can't with this solution. You might have to use Niet the Dark Absols solution.